# Dart: const и final в чем разница?

Tags: const, dart, final

В чем разница и сходство в Dart'е const и final

Объясните для "чайника" пожалуйста

Answer (score 11, accepted):

При использовании `final` - значение может быть присвоено один раз, но любое.

При использовании `const` - накладываются ограничения на присваиваемое значение, оно должно быть доступно в момент компиляции.

Так же `const` уже является `final`, однако в отличие от `final` значение не может быть изменено никаким образом.

Например:

```
final a = [1, 2, 3];
a.add(112);
print(a); // [1, 2, 3, 112]

const b = [1, 2, 3];
b.add(111); // Uncaught exception: Unsupported operation: add
print(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

const - мощный инструмент повышения производительности ( *в отличии от final* ) при создании, так называемых, канонических экземпляров.  Вы можете создать свой собственный класс, используя const конструктор и память не будет загромождена сотнями различных экземпляров. Вместо этого всякий раз, когда вы определяете одни и те же аргументы для const конструктора или фабрики, будет использован один и тот же канонический экземпляр.

Например:

```
class ConstClass {
  final int field1;   // Поля могут быть только типа final
  final List<String> field2;
  const ConstClass(this.field1, this.field2);
}

void run() {
  const constVariable = 42;
  const x = MyConstClass(constVariable, ['hi', 'dart']);
}
```